# What are the differences between sqlite3_bind_blob() & sqlite3_bind_blob64()?

Tags: c, sqlite, blob

What are the differences between [sqlite3_bind_blob()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) & [sqlite3_bind_blob64()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html)?

Comment: The type of the length argument.

Comment: Oh, OK. Thank you, @Shawn. So then the third argument to each routine can contain at most 2147483647 (`INT_MAX`) bytes for [sqlite3_bind_blob()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) or 18446744073709551615 bytes (according to [SQLite 64-Bit Integer Types](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/int64.html)) for [sqlite3_bind_blob64()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html).

Comment: Not in practice; see https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_length

Comment: Oh, word. Thanks, @Shawn. Well that says: "The current implementation will only support a string or BLOB length up to 2³¹-1 or 2147483647". If that's true, then what's the point of [sqlite3_bind_blob64()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html)?

Comment: Beats me (and storing a blob anywhere close to that size in any database is a bad idea)